# AVL Tree - Cannot pass root to the insert method

Tags: c++, class, object, search, tree

I am having a problem with an AVL Tree designed in C++ for my class. The teacher pointed out that we CANNOT use the **struct { }**, so we are forced to create a **Node** class and a **Tree** class or, eventually, an unique class.

The problem we have is on passing the root node pointer from the main to the insert function, that allows us to insert new strings in our Binary Research Tree.

Here is the code we wrote till now (it is in our language, basically Nodo = Node and Albero = Tree). Thanks in advance for any help you can give us:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/* -------- CLASSE: NODO -------- */

class Nodo {
public:
    string vocabolo;
    Nodo* left;
    Nodo* right;
    Nodo();
    ~Nodo() { }; // Distruttore inline
};

// Costruttore di Nodo
Nodo::Nodo() {
    left = right = NULL;
}

/* -------- CLASSE: ALBERO BINARIO DI RICERCA BILANCIATO -------- */

class Albero {
/*
 private:
    Nodo* root;
*/
public:
    int height(Nodo* nodo);
    int heightDifference(Nodo *nodo);
    void inorder(Nodo *radice);
    Nodo* balance(Nodo* nodo);
    Nodo* ll_rotate(Nodo* padre);
    Nodo* lr_rotate(Nodo* padre);
    Nodo* rl_rotate(Nodo* padre);
    Nodo* rr_rotate(Nodo* padre);
    Nodo* insert(Nodo* nodo, string nuovoVocabolo);
    Nodo* returnRoot();
    Albero();
    ~Albero() { }; // Distruttore inline
};

// Costruttore di Albero
Albero::Albero() {
   // root = NULL;
}

/*
Nodo* Albero::returnRoot() {
    return root;
} */

int Albero::height(Nodo* nodo) {
    int altezza = 0; // Imposto altezza iniziale a zero. Rimarrà così se passo puntatore a root.
    if (nodo != NULL) {
        int l_height = height(nodo->left);
        int r_height = height(nodo->right);
        int max_height = max(l_height, r_height);
        altezza = max_height + 1;
    }
    return altezza;
}

int Albero::heightDifference(Nodo* nodo) {
    int l_height = height(nodo->left);
    int r_height = height(nodo->right);
    int b_factor = l_height - r_height;
    return b_factor;
}

Nodo* Albero::ll_rotate(Nodo* padre) {
    Nodo* temp;
    temp = padre->left;
    padre->left = temp->right;
    temp->right = padre;
    return temp;
}

Nodo* Albero::rr_rotate(Nodo* padre) {
    Nodo* temp;
    temp = padre->right;
    padre->right = temp->left;
    temp->left = padre;
    return temp;
}

Nodo* Albero::lr_rotate(Nodo *padre) {
    Nodo *temp;
    temp = padre->left;
    padre->left = rr_rotate(temp);
    return ll_rotate(padre);
}

Nodo* Albero::rl_rotate(Nodo *padre) {
    Nodo *temp;
    temp = padre->right;
    padre->right = ll_rotate(temp);
    return rr_rotate(padre);
}

Nodo* Albero::balance(Nodo* nodo) {
    int b_factor = heightDifference(nodo);
    if (b_factor > 1) {
        if (heightDifference(nodo->left) > 0) {
            nodo = ll_rotate(nodo);
        } else {
            nodo = lr_rotate(nodo);
        }
    } else if (b_factor < -1) {
        if (heightDifference(nodo->right) > 0) {
            nodo = rl_rotate(nodo);
        } else {
            nodo = rr_rotate(nodo);
        }
    }
    return nodo;
}

Nodo* Albero::insert(Nodo *nodo, string nuovoVocabolo) {
    if (nodo == NULL) {
        nodo = new Nodo;
        nodo->vocabolo = nuovoVocabolo;
    } else if (nuovoVocabolo < nodo->vocabolo) {
        nodo->left = insert(nodo->left, nuovoVocabolo);
        nodo = balance(nodo);
    } else if (nuovoVocabolo >= nodo->vocabolo) {
        nodo->right = insert(nodo->right, nuovoVocabolo);
        nodo = balance(nodo);
    }
    return nodo;
}

void Albero::inorder(Nodo* radice) {
    if (radice == NULL) return;
    inorder(radice->left);
    cout << radice->vocabolo << " ";
    inorder(radice->right);
}

/* -------- FUNZIONE MAIN -------- */

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Albero tree;
    tree.insert(root, "ciao");
    tree.insert(root, "pino");
    tree.insert(root, "mauro");
    tree.insert(root, "francesco");
    tree.inorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to declare root, that is one problem (its commented out).

Comment: Don't look at the comments, they are result of some tests I did. Consider that there aren't comments

Comment: @Wired, edit the comments away. Post the exact code you want reviewed. Anything else is a huge waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I believe you have problems passing the root node pointer from the main to the insert function is because the root pointer is a private member of your Albero class. A private member of a class can only be accessed by other members within the (Albero) class.
link for more info : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_encapsulation.htm

What you can simply do to fix the problem is to create another function that will call your insert function.

```
void Albero::insertStart(string nuovoVocabolo)
{
   insert(root,nuovoVocabolo);
}
```

Now you can just make multiple calls to `insertStart()`

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Albero tree;
    tree.insertStart("ciao");
    tree.insertStart("pino");
    tree.insertStart("mauro");
    tree.insertStart("francesco");
    tree.inorder(root);     //you can apply a similar solution to this function
    return 0;
}
```